# При смене URL через NavLink не обновляется страница

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Есть общая компонента ActivePage

```
const App = (props) => {
return (
    <div className="app-wrapper">
        <Header />
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<MainPage/>}></Route>
            <Route path='/apart/*' element={<ApartPage />}></Route>
            <Route path='/active/*' element={<ActivePage />}></Route>
        </Routes>
    </div>
);
```

}

При смене URL через NavLink, URL меняется, но компонента не рендерится заново. Только после обновления страницы вручную

```
let items = otherArray.map((item,index) => (
   <div key={index} className="item">
     <img src={item.img} alt={item.title} />
     <div className="text">{item.title}
     <NavLink to={item.link} className="button button__blue">Подробнее</NavLink>
     </div>
   </div>
))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы запустить перерисовку компонента - передавайте в него какие либо свойства. (`props`), обновление `props` будет запускать перерисовку сразу.